# How to add category key to push notifications using java library

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

When I tried to add like this, the category key comes outside the aps dictionary. Please help me to add the category keyword inside the aps dictionary.
I have tried below code

```
payload.addCustomDictionary("category", "Alerts");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of the Javapns Jdk16 , `addCategory` field is added.

References:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fernandospr/javapns-jdk16/2.4.0

https://github.com/fernandospr/javapns-jdk16

Answer (score 0):

I think your referring to JAVAPNS here. As far as I know, 'Payload' class doesn't have a place holder for 'category'.

addCustomDictionary will add outside 'aps'

You will have to form 'aps' key with 'category' using some work around. (e.g. as below)

```
JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();
temp.put("category", "alert");
JSONObject myPayload = new JSONObject();
myPayload.put("aps", temp);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will add the category outside the aps dictionary. As a result, the categories are not recognised and their actions can t be implemented.

Comment: NO, this should add inside 'aps' only. In above code, temp is getting added as a payload inside 'aps'. Although, it would be better to use version with category part of the class.

Comment: No, I have tried it. The old category keys pairs as you mentioned adds outside the aps dictionary.